# IPTables quota not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-12.04

I've been struggling porting IPTable rules from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 12.04. The problem is that quota seems to be broken. Take this very simple instance of a quota rule.

> iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp -m quota --quota 500000 -j ACCEPT

On Ubuntu 10.04 this is what we see when we transfer bytes though eth0.

> (root@dev)-(~) $ iptables -L -t mangle -v | grep quota
>
> 146  111K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere            quota: 389148 bytes
>
> (root@dev)-(~) $ iptables -L -t mangle -v | grep quota
>
> 667  348K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere            quota: 152577 bytes

You can see the quota is going down while the used bytes are going up (second column).

However when I use the same rules on Ubuntu 12.04 the following happens.

> (root@LU1)-(~) $ iptables -L -t mangle -v | grep quota
>
> 14  2544 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere             quota: 500000 bytes
>
> (root@LU1)-(~) $ iptables -L -t mangle -v | grep quota
>
> 19  3188 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere             quota: 500000 bytes

The used bytes counter is going up but the quota is not going down. However it is counting it and if the quota is used up it will continue to the next rule. There is a second problem though because when you reboot the server, and you save the rules, the quota gets reset again even if it was all used up.

So basically there are two problems: The quota is not visibly going down and it resets on reboot even though I'm saving the rules.

Kernel on Ubuntu 12.04 is 3.2.0-44-generic
lsmod output: http://sprunge.us/OfEc

Can anybody explain to me what's happening and where this difference between behaviour is coming from? Or even better propose a solution? I am really stuck on this and I would appreciate any of you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question when digging through the kernel changes.

I've stumbled upon [this commit.](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=49daf6a22622d4e1619aeaad5f9f0472bf89daff) The thing I assumed was a bug was actual intended behaviour by the patcher. I've made a patch on the recent 3.2 kernel to revert this commit and everything works again. I hope this might save somebody else some hours of googling.